# IntelliJ plugin: how to add a toggle box to main toolbal

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea

I need to write a plugin for Eclipse and IntelliJ, I want to create a check box just as the `Toggle Mark Occurrences` of toolbal of Eclipse. I have finished the Eclipse development, but I can not find the solution of IntelliJ.

For Eclipse: I just need to config `style="toggle"` of the `command` element in `plugins.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CheckboxAction class as the base class for your action.

Note that the main toolbar is hidden by default in recent versions of IntelliJ IDEA, and also the available space there is very much limited by the screen width, so adding a checkbox there does not seem to be the best possible UI solution.